# forcing EDIT of access backend database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

i have about 20 users who have their own access front end and write to a backend.

i need to do an update to the backend, and every time i try to do it offhours, it seems that someone is still logged on because the file is locked!

how do i get around this? i do tell the users to log off at the end of the day but a lot of them forget! is there a way to force them off?

can i disconnect someone from an access database?

Comment: See http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=79802

Comment: @remou yes thats a great solution if you already have the backend open, however the backend is locked currently for editing

Comment: Have you checked the ldb for who is in? http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0055.htm

Comment: Just open the ldb with a text editor. You should something like: ComputerName      Admin

Comment: You will also find list users here: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/ADO_Schemas. It uses schemas, so it will run in VBScript with a little tweaking.

Comment: @remou thanks so much actually your first linked worked amazingly well  please put it as an answer and ill mark it right

Comment: @remou sweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeett hank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Idle Detect/Inactivity Timeout](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/idledetecttimeout.htm)

[How to determine who is logged on to a database by using Microsoft Jet UserRoster in Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285822)

I don't expect any points for my answer as Remou already gave you these.  But whenever reasonable I prefer to give pages with links to the official KB articles rather thwn who knows how mangled up code can get in a forum.  Including this one.